# How to block certain websites from being accessed through a C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am Developing a network monitoring software, through which I need to block a few websites from being accessed. I am currently doing so, by getting all the active TCP connections, then, getting the remote address from it and checking it against a list. I do this every 2/3 seconds with the help of a timer.

But, websites, sometimes use more than one IP address. How do I check all of them? I am not too proficient in C#, so please explain in simple terms.

Also, How do I find out which browser is accessing a particular website. Say I am running facebook on Chrome and other sites on firefox, how do I find out which application is runnign facebook?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but why not block sites on network basis, but try to make it work in a C# application.

Comment: I am developing the software as a project for my college. Plus, I want it so that workstations won't be able to access certain websites during certain hours. And in case of violation, the server application will be intimated.

Comment: does this apply on one system? if so,add the hostnames to the host file and point them to google's ip or something

Comment: No. A copy of the application will be installed on multiple systems in a LAN. Which is why it won't make much sense to edit the host file. Quite a few suggested the use of keyloggers, But I don't wish to use one.

Comment: WHy not approach it from the other angle? i.e. only allow certain sites to be access, e.g. google.com, wikipedia, awesomeresources.com. etc and summarily block everything else unless someone makes a compelling case to allow a certain site.

Comment: That'd be too restrictive.